# azure single sign out error: Signout failed. The initiating application is not a participant in the current session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, single-sign-on

following error when i logut from azure website:

**Signout failed. The initiating application is not a participant in the current session.**

locally its working and also on the production site. But at this "dev" site i receive above error.

Comment: David, if you're still seeing this error - could you please get me a fiddler trace of the error scenario? thanks

Comment: yes still same error. hmm what exactly should i show you from fiddler? sorry  but havent used fiddler that much

Comment: I would like to see the trace of the entire flow. However make sure that the trace doesn't have credentials of a production account -  either use a test account or change password before and after the trace. Make sure that https decrypt is enabled in fiddler options. Thanks

Comment: Contact me on http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/contact and I'll start an email conversation with you where you can share the trace and the code.

Comment: @DushyantGill Once this is resolved can you please post the solution back here for future visitors?

Comment: @David did you manage to solve it? I am running into the same issue and nothing I do seems to help, I've deleted and recreated the app, the ad and everything else a dozen times... Please help me :)